while integrating Firebase database in to Flutter code
While I am integrating my Firebase using Flutter code. It make error from different files. So, the I can't able to see my actual output.
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_trends/firebase_options.dart';

void main()async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


The above is my main dart file.
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
2
Invalid depfile:
C:\src\Trends\flutter_trends\.dart_tool\flutter_build\3730e87ac6b7c138f4c264e3af8c90cc\kernel_snapshot.d
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'shop_app' in 'package:shop_app/screens/splash/splash_screen.dart'.
/C:/Users/Welcome/Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/flex.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'package:shop_app/screens/splash/splash_screen.dart'
import 'package:shop_app/screens/splash/splash_screen.dart';
       ^
/C:/Users/Welcome/Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/flex.dart:7:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/Welcome/Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/routes.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'routes.dart';
       ^
/C:/Users/Welcome/Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/flex.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/Welcome/Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/theme.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'theme.dart';


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\Users\Welcome\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
